# Share data between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I am making a bugtracker app on android where i have a class called Task, which has a field "category" which defines if the task is done, in progress or have to do.

I have a fragment of ideas "Projects" where I added to set the ViewModel

```
public class ProjectFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "ProjectFragment";

private UserViewModel model;
private GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_projects, container, false);

    model = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(UserViewModel.class);
    GridView gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview_project);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Project temp = Objects.requireNonNull(model.getCurrentuser().getValue()).getProjects().get(position);
            model.setCurrproject(temp);
            Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick: " + temp.getProjectName());
            model.setTodoTasks(TaskSorter.getSortedTaskList(temp, "TODO"));
            model.setInprogressTasks(TaskSorter.getSortedTaskList(temp, "IN PROGRESS"));
            model.setDoneTasks(TaskSorter.getSortedTaskList(temp, "DONE"));

        }
    });
    gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(requireActivity(), Objects.requireNonNull(model.getCurrentuser().getValue()).getProjects());
    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    model.getCurrentuser().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(User user) {
            gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openProjectDialog();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I also have 3 fragment for the corresponding categories where I observe the changes.

```
public class FragmentToDo extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "FragmentToDo";

private ListView listView;
private UserViewModel model;
private ListViewAdapter listViewAdaptertodo;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo, container, false);
    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.todo_list);
    model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
    model.gettodoTasks().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
            listViewAdaptertodo.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i(TAG, "onChanged: todo");
        }
    });
    initTodo();
    return view;
}

private void initTodo(){
    listViewAdaptertodo = new ListViewAdapter(requireActivity(), model.gettodoTasks().getValue());
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdaptertodo);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            openTask();
        }
    });
}
```

All the 3 fragments looks like this, with different names of course. Whenever I click on a project some change happen, but not in all of them. The 3 categories are hold by a ViewPager, but im not sure where the problem is. In case heres the code for that too:

```
public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {

private static SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
private ArrayList<Task> todo;
private ArrayList<Task> inp;
private ArrayList<Task> done;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, container, false);
    sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragments(new FragmentToDo(), "To Do");
    sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragments(new FragmentInProgress(), "In Progress");
    sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragments(new FragmentDone(), "Done");
    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    return view;
}
```

}

Maybe the problem is whenever I define context and lifecycle owners, because as I am a novice android developer, i still know few thing about these topics.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple and not extensible way - eventbus, [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), for example.

And preferred way- move your app logic from fragments to other components, with data passing only in 1 way. I.e there is component, that exposes some sort of model of your screen, that get's updated - and fragment/view/activity reflect that change. You can check sample app [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)